# Show Travis-CI build status on Github Pull Request Page

Tags: github, travis-ci

How do you configure Github's pull request review page to show Travis-CI build status?

I remember Github automatically showing build status for some of my repos configured to build using Travis-CI, but Github has stopped doing this. Whether the build passed or succeeded, Github would show the status near the "Merge pull request" button. Now I have to manually search for the pull request in Travis-CI.

Has this feature been discontinued by Github, or is there some new manual configuration needed to re-implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This discussion thread](https://travis-ci.community/t/travis-ci-build-no-longer-showing-as-check-on-github-pull-request-page/6955/6) explained the issue.

The solution was to:

1. revoke access to Travis-CI in Github
2. logout of Travis-CI
3. log back in to Travis-CI.

Travis-CI then automatically asked for Github credentials, and afterwards Github again shows Travis-CI build status in a check.

Answer (score 0):

The legacy integration has been disabled and you need to perform the migration to the GitHub app integration.  See the instructions here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/migrate/legacy-services-to-github-apps-migration-guide/

Note that if you are not the owner on the repo, you will need to request adding Travis access to the appropriate person.